# Stream.reduce(Float,BinaryOperator) BinaryOperator refers which functional interface method?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

For Example,

```
List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<Product>();  
productsList.add(new Product(1,"HP Laptop",25000f));  
productsList.add(new Product(2,"Dell Laptop",30000f));  
productsList.add(new Product(3,"Lenevo Laptop",28000f));  
productsList.add(new Product(4,"Sony Laptop",28000f));  
productsList.add(new Product(5,"Apple Laptop",90000f));  

Float totalPrice = productsList.stream()  
                               .map(product->product.price)  
                               .reduce(0.0f,(sum, price)->sum+price);   
System.out.println(totalPrice);
```

Here which is the functional interface, `(sum, price)->sum+price` is referring to?

Comment: just moved the comment to its own answer then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you mentioned "functional interface *method*": [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) is actually calling [`apply` of `BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html#apply(T,U)) (from which [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) extends).

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `Stream` Javadoc:

> `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`

`(sum, price)->sum+price` implements a `BinaryOperator<Float>` in your example.

This functional interface has a method that accepts two arguments of the same type (`Float` in your case) and returns a result of that same type.